# Prevent VSCode from populating "files.associations" in C++ projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I love VSCode, but there a thing that is getting me mad about. I am using it with C++ (that was I tagged the ask with C++ too), and **everytime** that I open a file using CMD+Click it pollutes the `.vscode/settings.json` with garbage (see bellow). Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

```json
{
  "files.associations": {
    "iostream": "cpp",
    "memory_resource": "cpp",
    "__bit_reference": "cpp",
    "__config": "cpp",
    "__debug": "cpp",
    "__errc": "cpp",
    "__hash_table": "cpp",
    "__locale": "cpp",
    "__mutex_base": "cpp",
    "__node_handle": "cpp",
    "__split_buffer": "cpp",
    "__threading_support": "cpp",
    "__tree": "cpp",
    "__verbose_abort": "cpp",
    "array": "cpp",
    "atomic": "cpp",
    "bitset": "cpp",
    "cctype": "cpp",
    "charconv": "cpp",
    "clocale": "cpp",
    "cmath": "cpp",
    "complex": "cpp",
    "cstdarg": "cpp",
    "cstddef": "cpp",
    "cstdint": "cpp",
    "cstdio": "cpp",
    "cstdlib": "cpp",
    // SNIP
    "cstring": "cpp",
    "algorithm": "cpp"
  },
}
```

Comment: Why do you object to that?  It makes your experience better.  It not like you're paying extra for storing those bytes.

Comment: Because it is a lot of garbage, I like things clean.

Comment: that is because some dudes decided to skip the extension for stdlib include files, because HP also had an stdlib with the same names

Comment: if you will never open any of these files you can delete them, or set the languageID manually

Comment: It's not garbage.  It's useful, and it's in a file you don't look at very often.  Really, you need to focus on things that matter.